# Opening a new small window with javascript through HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying this for an hour and I can't figure out how to open a small window through HTML link. Basicly.

```
function myFunction() {
  var waypointsai = document.getElementById('waypointsai');
  var waypointas = document.getElementById('waypoints').value;

  waypts.push({
    location: waypointas,
    stopover: true
  });
  atvzd.push(waypointas);
  waypointsai.innerHTML += '<a href="#" onclick="newWindow(' + waypointas + ');">' + waypointas + '</a>';
}


waypointsai.innerHTML += '<a href="#" onclick="newWindow(' + waypointas + ');">' + waypointas + '</a>';
```

Basicly I need to have a function that opens a new window called `/whatever.php?variable=waypointas`. And that waypointas is what user inputs to an array.

So let's say my `waypointas = tree;` How I open a small window called `/whatever.php?variable=tree` ? I'm out of ideas I hope I clarified my situation clearly.

Comment: When you say window, do you mean you want to open a new browser tab? Or that you want it to fetch the content from said source, and paste that content onto your existing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the code

```
onclick="newWindow(' + waypointas + ');">
```

is going to generate code that looks like

```
onclick="newWindow(tree);">
```

so it will expect a variable tree to be defined. You need to add missing quotes

```
onclick="newWindow(\'' + waypointas + '\');">'
```

Now the problem with this is if tree contains a `'` it will throw an error.

and if you do not have a newWindow method, you need to create one that calls `window.open()`. [See the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) on how to set the size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html pop up window like this

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

And use query string to pass data.

You can also create overlay but that will required some javascript.

And you can also use bootstrap modal, very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width and height of a new window.

Try

`window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank', 'width=500, height=300');`